# Align image in title panel in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

If i write:

```
ui <- fluidPage (
  titlePanel(title=div("mytitle", img(src="mypicture.jpeg")))
)
```

then I get the image next to the text. How to align it to the right of the app screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
ui <- fluidPage (
  titlePanel(title=div("mytitle", 
                       img(src="mypicture.jpeg", 
                           style="position:absolute;right:15px;z-index:1000000;")))
)
```

The large `z-index` ensures the image is in front of everything.

Comment: the icon now gets behind navbarMenu. How to put it in front of everything?

Comment: @stakowerflol Not sure to understand, you have not posted a full code. What about `style="position:absolute;right:15px;z-index:1000000")` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
ui <- fluidPage (
  titlePanel(title=div("mytitle", img(src="mypicture.jpeg", style = "float:right;")))
)
```

Comment: the icon now gets behind navbarMenu. How to put it in front of everything?